# flutter vscode simulator emulaor でのhotreload と　buildの不具合

Tags: xcode, android-studio, vscode, flutter

flutter vscode androidstudio xcodeを用いてflutterに入門しております

xcodeとandroidstudioでhotreloadが効きません　
runを押すとそれぞれのsimulatorにおいてきちんと動作します
androidの実機ではhotreloadもrunも動作します

vscodeも同様です
vscodeは加えて、command paletteにおいて、flutter new projectをすると
名前入力までは可能ですがenterを押してもfinderは起動しません

Answer (score 0):

原因は不明ですが、全てアンインストールしてから再度インストールしなおしたらできました。